# Run docker on Heroku with arguments

Tags: docker, heroku

So, I am trying to run a Docker image (from docker hub) on Heroku.

An example of how I would run it locally:

```sh
docker run user/image -someoption $SOME_ENV_VAR
```

I have seen countless ways to run docker images on Heroku, but none show how to use arguments.

So how do I run a docker image on Heroku with arguments (from environnement).

Thanks in advance, 
Robin

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible as Heroku does not give you access to `docker run`.

You should be able to define [ConfigVars](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars) which are injected as env variables into the Docker containers (or alternatively build a new image starting from the one you want to run)